# (index):19 Uncaught ReferenceError: Search is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup

Tags: javascript, html, api, for-loop, onkeyup

i'm making an app with marvel's api and in this app i'm trying to put a search bar but i'm not getting it.

Every time I try to search for a name in this api the function `Search()` it is undefined in the html.

I don't understand how the function is not defined in the html.

What can i do to change this ?

```js
const timeStamp = "1622146184";
const privateKey = "somekey";
const publicKey = "someotherkey";
const md5 = "b34f17bceca201652c24e9aa21777da9";
const Hero = document.querySelector('article');
const input = document.getElementById('myInput');
 fetch(`http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?ts=${timeStamp}&apikey=${publicKey}&hash=${md5}&limit=6`).then((response)=> {
    return response.json();
 }).then((jsonParsed)=>{
     jsonParsed.data.results.forEach(element => {
         const srcImage = element.thumbnail.path + '.' +  element.thumbnail.extension;
         const nameHero = element.name;
         createHero(srcImage, nameHero, Hero);
  },
  
  function Search() {
    // Declare variables
    const filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    const textName2 = nameHero;
    // Loop through all textName2st items, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i <= textName2.length; i++) {
    const p = textName2[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
      txtValue = p.textContent || p.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        textName2[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        textName2[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
    })
    console.log(jsonParsed);
 })
function createHero(srcImage, nameHero, divToAppend){
    const divPai = document.createElement('section');
    const textName = document.createElement('p');
    const img = document.createElement('img');

    textName.textContent = nameHero;
    img.src= srcImage;
    divPai.appendChild(img);
    divPai.appendChild(textName);
    divToAppend.appendChild(divPai);

    divPai.classList.add("personagem");
}
```

```html
<main>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="Search()" placeholder="Search for names.." />
    <article id="herois"></article>
</main>
```

Comment: You might want to remove your public and private keys

Comment: If that's really your code, you are missing some closing `}` and `)`. So your `Search` function is defined within the `then` handler of the `fetch` and thus of course not globally available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `search` function is `undefined` because the `fetch` isn't closed properly. I'm also guessing that you only want to make a request when the user has actually entered some search query. I don't see multiple `article` elements so don't really know what to do with this. But do note that in this case you might as well use `getElementById`. And if there are multiple articles with the same `id` that it won't work.

```js
const timeStamp = "1622146184";
const privateKey = "somekey";
const publicKey = "someotherkey";
const md5 = "b34f17bceca201652c24e9aa21777da9";
const Hero = document.getElementById('herois');
const input = document.getElementById('myInput');
 
  
 async function Search() {
    console.log(input.value);
    await fetch(`http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?ts=${timeStamp}&apikey=${publicKey}&hash=${md5}&limit=6`)
    .then( response => {
      return response.json();
   })
   .then(jsonParsed => {
      console.log(jsonParsed);
      jsonParsed.data.results.forEach(element => {
        const srcImage = element.thumbnail.path + '.' +  element.thumbnail.extension;
        const nameHero = element.name;
        createHero(srcImage, nameHero, Hero);
      });
    });
    // Declare variables
    const filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    const textName2 = nameHero;
    // Loop through all textName2st items, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i <= textName2.length; i++) {
      const p = textName2[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
      txtValue = p.textContent || p.innerText;
      
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        textName2[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        textName2[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
}
 
function createHero(srcImage, nameHero, divToAppend){
    const divPai = document.createElement('section');
    const textName = document.createElement('p');
    const img = document.createElement('img');

    textName.textContent = nameHero;
    img.src= srcImage;
    divPai.appendChild(img);
    divPai.appendChild(textName);
    divToAppend.appendChild(divPai);

    divPai.classList.add("personagem");
}
```

```html
<main>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onchange="Search()" placeholder="Search for names.." />
    <article id="herois"></article>
</main>
```